# how was this distortion effect made?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

i was wonderning how was this effect created on photoshop.
I tried usingthe fluidity filter and combining other things with it like: blur and pixelate but i did not get a good result.
I need it for a project. Help will be appreciated.[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 1):

The bird is clipped very carefully out of the background and placed into another layer. The background can now be other than the original.

The bird is stretched with Smudge brush. Use the maximum strength for non-fading stretching. The movement can be limited fully horizontal by pressing Shift at the same time and the affected area can be limited by making a selection.